# Using JavaScript, how do you get elements with a specific className that's inside another element by using getElementByClassName?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, getelementsbyclassname

Hi stackoverflow experts, I have this problem/question, please help me here.

I have this code; the HTML is software generated so it's not very efficient I know, we don't have to worry about that. I want to write the jQuery part completely in JavaScript, I don't want to use jQuery, just plain JavaScript. How can I do it?

```js
$(".skillbar-container").each(function() {

    var x = $(this).find(".skillbar-percent").html();
    x =  x.replace(/\s+/g, '');

    $(this).find(".skillbar-bar").width(x + "%");
});
```

```css
.skillbar-container {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.skillbar-texts {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.skillbar-title {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.percent-mark {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}
.skillbar-percent {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
.skillbar {
    height: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.skillbar-bar {
    width: 63%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="skillbars">
  
  <div class="skillbar-container team-skillbar">
    <div class="skillbar-texts">
      
      <div class="skillbar-title">
        Sales Management
      </div>
      
      <div class="percent-mark">
        %
      </div>
      
      <div class="skillbar-percent wf-affected">
        76
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="skillbar">
      <div class="skillbar-bar">
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="skillbar-container team-skillbar">
    <div class="skillbar-texts">
      
      <div class="skillbar-title">
        Sales Management
      </div>
      
      <div class="percent-mark">
        %
      </div>
      
      <div class="skillbar-percent wf-affected">
        15
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="skillbar">
      <div class="skillbar-bar">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my attempt:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("skillbar-container");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var y = x[i].getElementsByClassName("skillbar-percent").innerHTML;
    var z = x[i].getElementsByClassName("skillbar-bar");
    z.style.width = y + '%';
  }
}
myFunction();
```

But it doesn't work, apparently this: `document.getElementsByClassName("skillbar-container")getElementsByClassName("skillbar-bar");` won't work, querySelector is not supported yet too.

So what should I do?

Comment: almost there, `x[i].getElementsByClassName` returns an "array", so you need to loop it like you do the first call...

Comment: .. returns a `Live NodeList`, which is array-like.  Calling it an array, even quoted, is a disservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Collected the 2 classes into NodeLists
2. Converted the 2 NodeLists into arrays.
3. Iterated through 2 for loops (one nested within the other)
4. On the first loop, the text from percent was extracted (didn't need regex)
5. Made sure it'll be a number with `parseInt`
6. Stored that number in an array `stats[]`
7. On the second loop, used the corresponding index of `stats[j]`to be the new width of the corresponding bar.
8. Added a few more bars because it's fun. :P

### SNIPPET

```js
var skBar = document.getElementsByClassName('skillbar-bar');
var skPer = document.getElementsByClassName('skillbar-percent');
var barArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(skBar);
var perArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(skPer);
var i;
var j;
var stats = [];

for (i = 0; i < perArr.length; i++) {
  var x = perArr[i].textContent;
  x = parseInt(x, 10);
  stats.push(x);
  console.log('percent: '+x);
  
  for (j = 0; j < barArr.length; j++) {
    var y = stats[j];
    barArr[j].style.width = y + "%";
    
  }
}
```

```css
.skillbar-container {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.skillbar-texts {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.skillbar-title {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.percent-mark {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
.skillbar-percent {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
.skillbar {
  height: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.skillbar-bar {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="skillbars">

  <div class="skillbar-container team-skillbar">
    <div class="skillbar-texts">

      <div class="skillbar-title">
        Sales Management
      </div>

      <div class="percent-mark">
        %
      </div>

      <div class="skillbar-percent wf-affected">
        76
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="skillbar">
      <div class="skillbar-bar">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="skillbar-container team-skillbar">
    <div class="skillbar-texts">

      <div class="skillbar-title">
        Sales Management
      </div>

      <div class="percent-mark">
        %
      </div>

      <div class="skillbar-percent wf-affected">
        15
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="skillbar">
      <div class="skillbar-bar">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="skillbar-container team-skillbar">
    <div class="skillbar-texts">

      <div class="skillbar-title">
        Sales Management
      </div>

      <div class="percent-mark">
        %
      </div>

      <div class="skillbar-percent wf-affected">
        92
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="skillbar">
      <div class="skillbar-bar">
      </div>
    </div>
      
      

  </div>
  
    <div class="skillbar-container team-skillbar">
    <div class="skillbar-texts">

      <div class="skillbar-title">
        Sales Management
      </div>

      <div class="percent-mark">
        %
      </div>

      <div class="skillbar-percent wf-affected">
        41
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="skillbar">
      <div class="skillbar-bar">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
    <div class="skillbar-container team-skillbar">
    <div class="skillbar-texts">

      <div class="skillbar-title">
        Sales Management
      </div>

      <div class="percent-mark">
        %
      </div>

      <div class="skillbar-percent wf-affected">
        50
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="skillbar">
      <div class="skillbar-bar">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Not a problem, that's a neat idea, it was fun refactoring it.